# What is the function of 的 in the sentence below?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

**在有形的以太**

It should mean "*here in tangible ether*" but I don't understand the function of **的**.

Can't I say the exact same thing writing it like that: **在有形以太** 
?

Comment: Might be helpful if you could provide the full sentence, if not the paragraph, on where this phase exists.

Comment: It's a sort of poem I red in a book: 还活着 / 在有形的以太 / 独自但真实

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between an adjective and a noun, you can add a 的 if you like.

美麗的姑娘 beautiful girl
好玩的游戲 entertaining game
複雜的語法 complicated grammar

Adding the 的 is the norm if the adjective has two characters. But it's possible to leave it out:

黑暗森林 dark forest
意外事故 unexpected accident
美好時光 happy time

Why did the poet use 的 here? Some possibilities:
- 以太 is an unusual word, putting a 的 before it makes the sentence easier to understand.
- The poet may have liked the flow of the sentence better with 的.
- Using 的 here is more normal than not using it.

Comment: What if he didn't use it? The sentence would have been wrong or something else?

Comment: @UsernameNotValid999 The sentence would still be OK without it, but might be a bit harder to understand, because the word boundary is not as obvious.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

see any grammar on when to use or not to use (and when optional) structural particle （结构助词）的，
bkrs：有形 有形状的、感官能感觉到的，examples，iciba：有形财产、有形动产、有形固定财产、有形货物、有形贸易、有形商品、有形损耗、有形损耗、有形的翅膀，Linguee：有形的数据、有形的 公 共 产品 public goods、 有形的 破 坏 、有形的进展、有形的联 系、有 形 的基础，may conclude 的 not used mostly in commercial or financial standing expressions, but used in others like 以太